# Ionic / Cordova and Facebook Live API

Tags: facebook, angular, cordova, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework

I wanna use Facebook live Api to post a live streaming to my fb timeline (per example),

i find this docum. about fb live implementation in javascript :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video/exploring-live

but after googling in the net i dont find any infos for implement it to cordova or ionic 2/3

help pls, sry 4 my english, & thanks in advance ^_^

Comment: Did you come up with solution for this?

Comment: not yet, u can create it nativly on ios/android  :(